# Which is the prefered CGI technology?

Tags: java, linux, iis, cgi

I want to develop a CGI application that has to run under Windows and Linux (IIS and Apache)

What is the best technology to do that?
I would prefer Java, but I am not sure if there is a problem with Java in an IIS.

Any experiences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For plain CGI, Java's startup time is going to be a killer when the process forks. It'll be frustrating even for the low loads you're expecting.

I would, honestly, recommend you use Python for this instead as it will have the right balance of startup / execution speed and "batteries included" features for CGI development.

Here's a link if you're intersted: http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html

Answer (score 2):

Completely depends on your application what

- What load are you expecting
- How complex will it be.
- Where will you store the data
- How secure does it need to be
- How skilled are you or your developers.
- What languages are you familiar with.

For a simple web app its hard to beat Vanilla php, using the LAMP stack with sqlite. As php will let you do almost anthing almost anywhere you need to be disciplined about how you structure your code -- but otherwise its a good solid working environment.

At the other end of the scale are the J2EE behemoths Weblogic and Websphere. These are monsters in terms of complexity and learning curve but if you are planning on 100s of transactions per second, in a secure environment with bullet proof reliability -- and you have deep pockets -- nothing will beat it.

The only sure answer form you post is IIS, ActiveScript .NET is out of the picture if you want to deploy under *nix or anything other than windows.

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't specify my requirements. actually i want to develop a simple app that communicates with my appserver. i want to replace an existing c++ cgi app. since i am not sure if i can use php on any webserver i would prefer a simple app.exe that i put on the server. and i think the requests for that cgi app would be like 1 per second at most. and it's nothing critical that is does.

Answer (score 1):

java and CGI is not a good match! If I really had to do a CGI then I would go wit Perl [CGI](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) module. Perl should work with IIS too, but I cannot confirm this.